# How to integrate the spring boot project generated by swagger with OSGi and deploy it in Apache karaf?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-karaf

How to integrate the spring boot project generated by swagger with OSGi and deploy it in Apache karaf?
How should I write my pom.xml and how to modify the startup class. If there is something not detailed, I will add it. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Please post your codes with your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. It's not strictly impossible but it would be a lot of work and struggle and you will not get any benefits out of it.

If you want SpringBoot - stick to that. You will sacrifice modularity, strong encapsulation, enforced clean architecture and bunch of other architectural thing that will matter a lot in the long run. But you will gain something that is easy to work with in the beginning and tons of code to copy/paste.

If you are playing the long game - I'd recommend to forget about SpringBoot and learn how to build modular OSGi applications. Recent version allow you to use popular technologies like [JAX-RS](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.jaxrs.html) and [CDI](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.enterprise/7.0.0/service.cdi.html). You can probably use one of the Swagger's JAX-RS generators and then convert the outcome to proper modular code. It may even be that there is a generator that generates OSGi JAX-RS code already.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This problem has been solved. I don't know much about this at present. I will continue to learn about OSGi.